# Unable to validate credentials using LDAP

Tags: c#, .net, ldap

I am new to LDAP and wanted to connect to a LDAP server using .Net to validate the user credentials. The following code returns an error:

> The LDAP server is unavailable

But the validation works fine in Java code. Kindly let me know where I have gone wrong.

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "LDAP://192.168.65.201:389/DC=be,DC=ndl,DC=CompanyName,DC=com"))
{
    bool a= pc.ValidateCredentials("myname@CompanyName.com","password"); 
}
```

Comment: Changed the code to access LDAP server:  
               
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, txtUsername.Text.ToString().Trim(), txtPassword.Text.ToString().Trim());
Object obj = entry.NativeObject;
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - `PrincipalContext` only works against **Active Directory**, not against any other LDAP server.

Secondly: you're specifying invalid parameters for the constructor. [Check out the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.principalcontext%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on what constructors are available for `PrincipalContext`.

You can define just a `ContextType` parameter, in which case the `PrincipalContext` is constructed against the current domain you're connected to:

```
var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
```

Or you can use a constructor with a second string parameter which signifies the **domain name** of your domain (**only** the domain name - **NOT** a complete LDAP path!):

```
var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "CompanyName.com");
```

Then you're connected to that specific domain, at the root level.

Or thirdly, you can specify a third parameter which defines the **container** in that domain to connect to:

```
var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "CompanyName.com", 
                               "CN=Users,DC=be,DC=ndl,DC=CompanyName,DC=com");
```

So you'll need to find the appropriate constructor and supply the correct parameters to get this to work - **if** you're using Active Directory.

Comment: Thanks Mars: Didn't realize that I was trying to connect to LDAP server using PrincipalContext.